# X11 not working on Mac after Xcode 12.4 upgrade

Tags: macos, imagemagick, x11, xquartz

I need to get X11 working on a Mac, or run ImageMagick without X11.

After upgrading Xcode to 12.4, I first noticed ImageMagick display was hanging.

I rebooted the machine. It started without XQuartz. I could not then re-open it with the XQuartz icon in Applications/Utilities. I could start XQuartz from a terminal, but it would immediately close itself again.

After 'brew upgrade xquartz' I had a version that would run from a terminal and stay up, but xclock and other basic X11 tools do not run.

'echo $DISPLAY' gives...
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.XGhnBj01N9/org.xquartz:0

I re-built ImageMagick from source with ./configure --with-modules
'make test' passed.

I am using a late 2013 MacBook Pro, running Big Sur 11.3.

Addendum:

There seem to be two versions of this question: I corrected XTools to Xcode and added a postscript, but it is not here. Odd.

At one point --with-modules was needed for X11. This has changed several times. I tried building it without too. It was working --with-modules before it stopped working. I have also tried the 'homebrew' install.

There was a new Xquartz release for Mac on the 25th April, with the same 2.8.1 number as before. That was about the date the Xcode 11.4 update happened. I have tried that but it did not help.

I can get 'clock' working if I export DISPLAY=:0, but that does not help ImageMagick, and may break other things.

Thanks to Mark Setchell for giving me something new to try. I built with ./configure --with-x. This seems to be just the same as my other build. When you run Xquartz in a terminal, and then run the build, something seems to be happening for about 10 seconds (there is progress thingy in the terminal tab) and then it stops but nothing appears. I can reset DISPLAY but that does not help anything but xclock, it would seem. 10 seconds is also slow fr something that used to pop straight up even with large images (and the one I am testing is tiny).

I know Homebrew has stopped supporting configurable builds: it just gives you ImageMagic in some standard state unless you find it under another name (as d12frosted/emacs-plus does for emacs).

Reply 6th May

My ImageMagick checkout is a clone from SourceForge at the end of last week. This was built with...
make clean
./configure --with-x --with-quantum-depth=32
make
sudo make install

identify -list configure gives this...

Path: /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.11//config-Q32HDRI/configure.xml

### Name                  Value

CC                    gcc
CFLAGS                 -I/usr/local/Cellar/webp/1.2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/webp/1.2.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libraw/0.20.2/include/libraw -I/usr/local/Cellar/libraw/0.20.2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/include/libpng16  -I/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.3_3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.48.4/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/2.8.0_1/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.48.4/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/fribidi/1.0.10/include/fribidi -I/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/2.8.0_1/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphite2/1.3.14/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/include/cairo -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pixman/0.40.0/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/include/libpng16 -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxcb/1.14_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxrender/0.9.10/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxext/1.3.4/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libx11/1.7.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxcb/1.14_1/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxau/1.0.9/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/xorgproto/2021.3/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openexr/2.5.5/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/local/Cellar/ilmbase/2.5.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/ilmbase/2.5.5/include/OpenEXR -I/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/liblqr/0.4.2_1/include/lqr-1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/include/openjpeg-2.4 -I/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libheif/1.11.0_2/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/aom/3.0.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/libde265/1.0.8/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/x265/3.5/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.47.1/include/graphviz -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/freetype/include/freetype2    -Wall -g -O2 -mtune=haswell -fexceptions -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -pthread -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=32
CODER_PATH            /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.11/modules-Q32HDRI/coders
CONFIGURE             ./configure  '--with-x' '--with-quantum-depth=32' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/pkgconfig'
CONFIGURE_PATH        /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick-7/
COPYRIGHT             Copyright (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
CPPFLAGS              -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
CXX                   g++
CXXFLAGS               -pthread
DEFS                  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
DELEGATES             bzlib fontconfig freetype heic jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr openjp2 pango png ps raw tiff video webp x xml zlib zstd
DISTCHECK_CONFIG_FLAGS  --disable-deprecated  --with-quantum-depth=32  --with-jemalloc=no  --with-umem=no  --with-autotrace=no  --with-fftw=no  --with-gslib=no  --with-fontpath=  --with-jxl=no  --with-rsvg=no  --with-wmf=no  --with-perl=no
DOCUMENTATION_PATH    /usr/local/share/doc/ImageMagick-7
EXEC-PREFIX           /usr/local
EXECUTABLE_PATH       /usr/local/bin
FEATURES              DPC HDRI Cipher
FILTER_PATH           /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.11/modules-Q32HDRI/filters
GIT_REVISION          18654:5bf34ccb1:20210425
HOST                  x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0
INCLUDE_PATH          /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7
LDFLAGS               -L/usr/local/lib
LIB_VERSION           0x70B
LIB_VERSION_NUMBER    7,0,11,10
LIBRARY_PATH          /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.11
LIBS                    -L/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/lib -llcms2 -ltiff -L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -lfreetype  -ljpeg   -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -llqr-1 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -L/usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.37/lib -lpng16 -lz      -L/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.13.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/freetype/lib -lfontconfig -lfreetype -L/usr/local/Cellar/libheif/1.11.0_2/lib -lheif -L/usr/local/Cellar/webp/1.2.0/lib -lwebpmux -lwebpdemux -lwebp -L/usr/local/Cellar/webp/1.2.0/lib -lwebp   -lXext    -lX11  -L/usr/local/Cellar/xz/5.2.5/lib -llzma -lbz2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/openexr/2.5.5/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/ilmbase/2.5.5/lib -lIlmImf-2_5 -lImath-2_5 -lHalf-2_5 -lIex-2_5 -lIexMath-2_5 -lIlmThread-2_5 -L/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/2.4.0/lib -lopenjp2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/pango/1.48.4/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.68.1/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/harfbuzz/2.8.0_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/cairo/1.16.0_5/lib -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lharfbuzz -lcairo -L/usr/local/Cellar/libraw/0.20.2/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.12/lib -lraw_r -lstdc++ -llcms2  -lxml2 -L/usr/local/Cellar/graphviz/2.47.1/lib -lgvc -lcgraph -lcdt -lz     -lm    -lpthread
NAME                  ImageMagick
PCFLAGS               -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=32
PREFIX                /usr/local
QuantumDepth          32
RELEASE_DATE          2021-04-24
SHARE_PATH            /usr/local/share/ImageMagick-7
SHAREARCH_PATH        /usr/local/lib/ImageMagick-7.0.11/config-Q32HDRI
TARGET_CPU            x86_64
TARGET_OS             darwin20.4.0
TARGET_VENDOR         apple
VERSION               7.0.11
WEBSITE               https://imagemagick.org

Path: [built-in]

### Name                  Value

DELEGATES             bzlib fontconfig freetype gvc heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png raw tiff webp x xml zlib
FEATURES              Cipher DPC HDRI
MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH /var/folders/rg/4gw1m9bs1d50c9fdrx4s2ysm0000gp/T
NAME                  ImageMagick
QuantumDepth          Q32

identify -version gives...

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.11-10 Q32 x86_64 2021-04-24 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI
Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype gvc heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png raw tiff webp x xml zlib

Comment: Your question raises other questions... 1) What is `Tools` please? 2) What is `XTools`? 3) You say you are happy to run **ImageMagick** without X11, surely that is running already, so you should be happy? 4) If `xclock` and `xterm` don't run, you can forget **ImageMagick** till they do run. 5) Configuring **ImageMagick** `-with modules` only allows you to compile your own processing modules, it doesn't build in X11.

Comment: You need to add `--with-x` to `./configure` if you want X11 support.

Comment: The **homebrew** version does not include X11.

Comment: I presume you ran `make -j 4` and `make install` after `./configure`? Did you delete the **homebrew** version of **ImageMagick**? Did you check the dates on the newly-built **ImageMagick** binaries? Did you try `identify -list configure` and `identify -version` after building and installing?

Comment: Yes, to both. I ran 'make' without the -j 4. I could tell I was accessing the right copy of ImageMagic because the Q32 flag was there in the version when I built for 32-bit quantization. Thanks for checking, though: I expect t will be obvious when I see it.

Comment: So, please click `edit` under your question and add in your build commands and the output from the 2 `identify` commands I suggested in previous comment.